# RVM install ruby 2.6.4 fails with makefile error: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_closure' is invalid in C99

Tags: ruby, rvm, macos-big-sur

**RVM rvm 1.29.12-next**

[macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) on an [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) chip

`rvm install 2.6.4` fails with:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/jason/.rvm/log/1626110300_ruby-2.6.4/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The makefile error is:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_closure' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    result = ffi_prep_closure(pcl, cif, callback, (void *)self);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is caused by the environment flags not being set in your shell.

You need to run `brew install libffi`, but to do that, the [environment variables](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/environment_variable#Noun) must be set in your shell.

`brew info libffi`

will tell you the variables you need:

For compilers to find libffi, you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"
```

For pkg-config to find libffi, you may need to set:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

For [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`), edit `~/.zshenv` and add:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Close and reopen your terminal window or `source ~/.zshrc` to load your changes.

Check your work with:

```
echo $LDFLAGS
```

Output:

```
-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib
```

---

```
echo $CPPFLAGS
```

Output:

```
-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include
```

---

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Output:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig
```

(confirm that the environment variables are correct)

Retry to install the rvm version you want to install.

Comment: Worked for macos big sur 11.4 with M1 and ruby 2.7.0. Make sure you install libffi with `brew install libffi` to see the required variables.

Comment: Also worked for `rbenv` ruby installations.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with `rvm` and Ruby 3.0.0. I want to reiterate that you need to actually `brew install libffi` and copy the specific env vars and paths for your system as opposed to just copy pasting the ones above.

Comment: @CaseyL - clarified, thank you

Comment: @JasonFB make sure to know that you would be overwriting these variables

Most of the libs compiled with make/cmake are 
 going to use `LDFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`, not sure what do you use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` for

Anyhow, that's how you do it saving previous value

`
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
`

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved in my case with the below commands.

```
brew install libffi
```

And setting variables in the *.zshenv* file.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"
```

Close the terminal and open a new one *or* use `source ~/.zshrc`.

Run the below command now.

```
rvm install 2.6.4
```

This was on an [M1 Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1_Pro_and_M1_Max) with [macOS v12.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey).